# image transition for javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, transition, smoothing

I have an image tag that can change image once hovered over. I would like to make this transition smooth. Something like a fade into the next image. This is the code I have now:

```
$('img').bind('mouseenter mouseleave', function() {
    $(this).attr({
        src: $(this).attr('data-other-src') 
        , 'data-other-src': $(this).attr('src') 
    })
});
```

I am a total beginner for javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the ms values for faster/slower transition, fades out then back in

```js
$('img').bind('mouseenter mouseleave', function() {
  var self = $(this);
  self.fadeTo(1000, 0.30, function() {
    self.attr({
      src: self.attr('data-other-src'),
      'data-other-src': self.attr('src')
    });
  }).fadeTo(500, 1);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Replacing the `src` attribute is "brutal": you cannot transition that.

In order to do this, you need your 2 images exist in the DOM at least during the transition.